# Monads in monoids

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, terminology, monoid, monads

This question is almost a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/443847/48558), but not quite.  There the person asked about examples and intuition, I am asking about terminology and applications, and I am addressing my question more to semigroup theorists than to category theorists.

Having background in group theory, when studying category theory I find it helpful to consider restrictions of different category-theoretic definitions to the cases when the category in question is a group or a monoid (viewed as categories with a single object).

When looking into monads, I have figured out that monads in a group are exactly the inner automorphisms of the group, together with the conjugating elements. In the case of monoids, a monad in a monoid $X$ is described by an endomorphism $\theta\colon X\to X$ together with two elements $m,h\in X$ such that:

1. $\forall x\in X$, $\theta(x)m = m\theta(\theta(x))$,
2. $\forall x\in X$, $\theta(x)h = hx$,
3. $m^2 = m\theta(m)$,
4. $m\theta(h) = mh = 1$.

*Do such endomorphisms of monoids have a special role in algebra? Do they have a special name?*

Comment: If $hm=1$ then you can show $\theta(x)=hxm$, so theta is an inner automorphism. In particular if $X$ is commutative then $\theta$ is always an inner automorphism.

Comment: This is obvious.

Comment: I wrote some blog posts about [Monads on Monoids](https://oscarcunningham.com/57/monads-on-monoids/) and [Adjunctions between Monoids](https://oscarcunningham.com/314/adjunctions-between-monoids/).